# Python 2.7.6: How do I clean up a class properly?

Tags: python-2.7, class

in the following and executable code you see a `SessionScope`()-class. In the `main`()-function the user can log on to his MySQL database server. We take a look in the class. There are two magic methods `(__enter__, __exit__)`,
that allows me to use the object easily with the `with`-statement. In this statement you also see the program uses session. When the `__exit__`()-method is
calling then the session is closed. BUT we know that will give the connection back to the connection pool of Engine. That means, its doesn't close the connection directly,
because the connection is pooling. So far so good. On GUI side the user has the option to log off. Well, let us imagine: After a very very very long work with the 
database the user wants the connection to be actually closed, but he doesn't wants the program closes itself. Later perhaps the user will log on again and continue working. Until then the program is still running without connection to 
the database. The user doesn't need the connection anymore.

That means for python, we don't need the `SessionScope`()-class anymore. In my case we can remove/clean up this class with `del session_scope` My idea is to re-implement the `__del__`()-method. In this method I want to
close all connections of the connection pool. If this class is cleared/removed all connections should be disconnected, that is the reason why I use the `del` in `log_out`()-function.

Is this the right way to do this?

TA, your Sophus

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError

class SessionScope(object):
    def __init__(self, dbms, dbdriver, dbuser, dbuser_pwd, db_server_host, dbport, db_name):

        self.dbms = dbms
        self.dbdriver = dbdriver
        self.dbuser = dbuser
        self.dbuser_pwd = dbuser_pwd
        self.db_server_host = db_server_host
        self.dbport = dbport
        self.db_name = db_name

        url = '{}+{}://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
           self.dbms, self.dbdriver, self.dbuser, self.dbuser_pwd, self.db_server_host, self.dbport, self.db_name)

        self.engine = create_engine(url, encoding='utf8', echo=True)

        # store a sessionmaker for this db connection object
        self._Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.session = self._Session()
        return self._Session()

    def __exit__(self, exception, exc_value, traceback):

        try:
            if exception:
                self.session.rollback()
            else:
                self.session.commit()
        finally:

            self.session.close()
            self.session = None

    def __del__(self):
        self.engine.dispose()

def log_out(session_scope):
    del session_scope

def main():
    dbm_system = raw_input("Which DBMS? (type for e.g. mysql): ")
    dbm_driver = raw_input("Which db-driver? (type for e.g. pymysql): ")
    db_host = raw_input("Server-Host: ")
    db_user = raw_input("Database-user: ")
    db_passwd = raw_input("User-Password: ")
    db_name = raw_input("Database Name: ")
    db_port = raw_input("Port: ")

    try:
        session_scope = SessionScope(dbm_system, dbm_driver, db_user, \
                    db_passwd, db_host, db_port, db_name)

        with session_scope as session:
            # Its just for testing.
            print session.execute("SELECT VERSION();")

        log_out(session_scope)

    except SQLAlchemyError as err:
        print "ERROR", err[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT #1:**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.exc import SQLAlchemyError

class SessionScope(object):
    def __init__(self, engine):

        self.engine = engine

        # store a sessionmaker for this db connection object
        self._Session = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        self.session = None

    def __enter__(self):
        self.session = self._Session()
        return self._Session()

    def __exit__(self, exception, exc_value, traceback):

        try:
            if exception:
                self.session.rollback()
            else:
                self.session.commit()
        finally:

            self.session.close()
            self.session = None

class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, dbms, dbdriver, dbuser, dbuser_pwd, db_server_host, dbport, db_name):

        self.dbms = dbms
        self.dbdriver = dbdriver
        self.dbuser = dbuser
        self.dbuser_pwd = dbuser_pwd
        self.db_server_host = db_server_host
        self.dbport = dbport
        self.db_name = db_name

        url = '{}+{}://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}'.format(
           self.dbms, self.dbdriver, self.dbuser, self.dbuser_pwd, self.db_server_host, self.dbport, self.db_name)

        self._Engine = create_engine(url, encoding='utf8', echo=True)

    def __enter__(self):
        return self._Engine

    def __exit__(self, exception, exc_value, traceback):
        '''
            Make sure the dbconnection gets closed
        '''
        self._Engine.dispose()

logged_in = True

def main():

    dbm_system = raw_input("Which DBMS? (type for e.g. mysql): ")
    dbm_driver = raw_input("Which db-driver? (type for e.g. pymysql): ")
    db_host = raw_input("Server-Host: ")
    db_user = raw_input("Database-user: ")
    db_passwd = raw_input("User-Password: ")
    db_name = raw_input("Database Name: ")
    db_port = raw_input("Port: ")

    try:
        with Engine(dbm_system, dbm_driver, db_user, \
                    db_passwd, db_host, db_port, db_name) as engine:

            while logged_in:
                with SessionScope(engine) as session:
                    # Its just for testing.
                    print session.execute("SELECT VERSION();")

    except SQLAlchemyError as err:
        print "ERROR", err[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The `__del__` method doesn't work like that. It's not called when a user does `del some_instance`, but when the interpreter's garbage collector sees that there are no live references to the object. Your `log_out` method does nothing, since the reference it is deleting is an extra one that's created to pass the session to it as an argument (the outside reference still remains).

I suspect you really want to have two different classes that both support the context manager protocol. This lets you have two nested `with` statements, one which last through an entire login and that only lasts for the length of one per database session. Something like this:

```
with Engine() as engine:
    while logged_in:
        with Session(engine) as session:
            do_stuff()
```

You may want another loop around the outer `with` so that the program doesn't exit after you log out.

Comment: Blckknght: first of all, TA for your help. I edited a new version of my code (Edit #1). Is that what you meant? Well In this new version, the program executes all the time until `logged_in` is False. In reality isn't feasible, because the user makes a manipulation. In reality I think the while-loop is sufficient, right?